# How to write the commutator subgroup in terms of the generators of the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

Let $G=\langle\ S\ |\ R\ \rangle$ be a finitely presented group. The commutator subgroup of $G$ is the group generated by $\{[a,b]\ |\ a,b\in G\}$ and is denoted by $[G,G]$, where $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$.

> **1. Is it true that $[G,G]$ is generated by $\{[s,t]\ |\ s,t\in S\}$ ?**

I need to show that any $[a,b]$ can be written as a word in $[s,t]$ but I am not sure if it can be done.

---

The above is a generalized question which I asked myself when considering the particular case below -

Let $W=\langle\ S\ |\ R\ \rangle$ where, $$S=\{s_1,\cdots,s_{2n}\}$$ $$R=\left\{s_i^2 : 1\le i\le 2n\right\}\bigcup\left\{(s_is_j)^2:1\le i,j\le 2n,j\neq i+n\right\}$$

> **2. Then is $[W,W]$ is generated by $\{[s_i,s_{i+n}]\ |\ 1\le i\le n \}$** ?

Thank you.

Comment: For the first part, $S_n$ gives rise to a basic counter example. $S_n$ is $2$-generated, which implies if the first claim is true then its commutator subgroup would be cyclic. But the commutator subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$ which is not cyclic for $n\geq 4$.

Comment: any word $[a,b]$ is already a word in *one* commutator: $[a,b]$ itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no. If $G$ is a free group of rank greater than $1$ then $[G,G]$ is not even finitely generated.

If what you were asking were true, then for any $2$-generator group $[G,G]$ would be cyclic, which is clearly not the case.

It is true in your specific example. In the case $n=1$, $W$ is the infinite dihedral group with $[W,W]$ generated by $[s_1,s_2]$.

For  general $n$, $W$ is the direct product of its subgroups $\langle s_i,s_{i+n}\rangle$, so $[W,W]$ is free abelian of rank $n$, with generators $[s_i,s_{i+n}]$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand why the general case it is not necessarily true now. What about the particular case I mentioned? Is it false there too?

Comment: See edit to answer.

Comment: I see that $W$ is the mentioned direct product and also that $[W,W]$ is abelian. But I can't see why it is free. I tried [using this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group#Relation_to_arbitrary_abelian_groups) by letting $A=W/[W,W]\cong\mathbb Z_2^{2n}$ but I can't see why ker$(\mathbb Z^{2n}\to\mathbb Z_2^{2n})$ is $[W,W]$. Thank you

Comment: In the case $n=1$ it is infinite cyclic. So in the general case it is the direct product of infinite cyclic groups i.e. free abelian.

Answer (score 7):

No, 1. is not true. There are groups $G$ where the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ may contain elements which are not commutators.
One example are the free groups. For instance, in the free group of rank $4$, freely generated by $x$, $y$, $z$, and $w$, the element $[x,y][z,w]$ of the commutator subgroup cannot be written in the form $[a,b]$ for some $a,b$ in the group.

Comment: Please see the edited question. I meant to ask if $[G,G]$ is generated by $\{[s,t]\ |\ s,t\in S\}$ not equal to it. Sorry for the confusion.