# Generating Set for Commutator group of 2 subgroups

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

This may well have been asked already, but I couldn't find a link.

If $A$, $B$ are subgroups of $G$, given generating sets for $A$ and $B$, is there a "nice" generating set for $[A,B]$?

I'm aware relations with commutators are rarely as nice as you'd hope for - hoping there's still a nice answer.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853992/how-to-write-the-commutator-subgroup-in-terms-of-the-generators-of-the-group).

Comment: @1123581321 This is false. It would imply $[A,A]=A$ for all groups $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H = \langle X \rangle$ and $K = \langle Y \rangle$, then $$[H,K] = \left\langle [x,y]^{hk} : x \in X, y \in Y, h \in H, k \in K \right\rangle.$$

This is an exercise in Suzuki, Group Theory II, Chapter 4.

Comment: Thank you!! Will try this